# jquery roundabout chrome & safari: image size and opacity is all wrong?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, opacity, image-resizing

Works fine on every browser but Chrome & Safari. I am using these js files:

```
<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery.scrollTo-min"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery.localscroll-min"></script>
```

And this doc ready function:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul#roundabout').roundabout({
      btnNext: '#next',
     btnPrev: '#previous',
     easing: 'easeInOutQuad'

  });
  });
 </script>
```

It applies to

```
<ul id="roundabout">
<li><img src="assets/img/barney.jpg"><br />
Barney</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/bert.jpg"><br />
Bert</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/coco.jpg"><br />
Coco</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/dolly-and-flo.jpg"><br />
Dolly &#38; Flo</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/marley.jpg"><br />
Marley</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/murphy.jpg"><br />
Murphy</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/ted.jpg"><br />
Ted</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/ruby.jpg"><br />
Ruby</li>
<li><img src="assets/img/theo.jpg"><br />
Theo</li>
</ul>
```

The result is that all the pictures are tiny, and the opacity isn't applied correctly. Has anyone else experienced this? Am stumped!